# Why the processing time of this query skyrockets when adding this "where" clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a query done without including some previous CTE's `ids` from previous queries. The query looks like this:

```
WITH
  people AS(
  SELECT
    rand() AS prob,
    [ STRUCT(name,
      address,
      id,
      [CAST(FLOOR(19*RAND()) AS INT64),
      CAST(FLOOR(19*RAND()) AS INT64),
      CAST(FLOOR(19*RAND()) AS INT64)] AS answers) ] AS person
  FROM
    `table_id`
  ORDER BY
    prob DESC
  LIMIT
    53370 ),
SELECT
  t1.* EXCEPT(col_1,
    col_2),
  prob,
  foo.person
FROM
  `table_id` t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    people,
    UNNEST(people.person) p) foo
ON
  foo.id= t1.id
```

So, until here, all good. The query runs in about 3.4 seconds, but it includes all the id, so the ids of CTE people are counted twice.

I added this "innocent" line at the end of the query in order to try filtering the ids

```
WHERE
  t1.id NOT IN (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    people,UNNEST(people.person))
```

And with this, the time goes skyrocket (easy 25 minutes and its not done). Why is this? The whole table has a size of 30.28 MB and 184.329 rows. How can I fix this and get the result I want? (exclude the ids of CTE `people` when joining the the table with the original table). Should I use other type of join or approach to get this done?

Comment: you probably need an index of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
where foo.id is null
```

You already have a `left join` in the query to the same data.  Just check that there is no match.

The problem with your query is probably a poor implementation of `NOT IN`.  I prefer `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` -- which is what I suggest.

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff, `where foo.id is null` just leave all the empty columns. There seems to be actually no row from the previous CTE :(